# how to declare functions in module in ruby

Tags: ruby

In the below code, what is the difference between declaring two methods differently. Second method is declared using `Week` but first method is declared without using `Week`. And we are also not able to access second method by the class object `d1`. It gives the error

```
undefined method `weeks_in_year' for #<Decade:0x2c08a28> (NoMethodError)
```

then what is the use of declaring methods using `Week` prefix in second method when it is of no use.

```
module Week
   def weeks_in_month
      puts "You have four weeks in a month"
   end
   def Week.weeks_in_year
      puts "You have 52 weeks in a year"
   end
end

class Decade
   include Week
end

d1=Decade.new
d1.weeks_in_month
d1.weeks_in_year
```

Answer (score 2):

The way you have defined the method `weeks_in_year` is a class method of the `Week` class, not an instance method. That's why it didn't get inherited and you got the error as you posted.

You can use [`module_function`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-module_function) to use the same method as a class method or instance method.

```
module Week
  def weeks_in_month
    puts "You have four weeks in a month"
  end

  def weeks_in_year
    puts "You have 52 weeks in a year"
  end

  module_function :weeks_in_year
end

class Decade
  include Week

  def wrapper_of_weeks_in_year
    weeks_in_year
  end
end

d1 = Decade.new

d1.weeks_in_month
# You have four weeks in a month
d1.wrapper_of_weeks_in_year
# You have 52 weeks in a year
Week.weeks_in_year
# You have 52 weeks in a year
```

While you will be using `module_function`, *The instance-method versions are made private*. That's why you need to use a wrapper method to call it as direct invocation is not possible.